# Is it possible to use boto3 to query gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if we could use boto3 to query gcp as we do for python. However the main examples I cam across work only for Buckets.
Is there any other python sdk for GCP?

Comment: Boto3 is an AWS SDK supporting AWS services. BigQuery is not a supported service. The reason that boto3 works with Cloud Storage is that Google added S3 emulation to Cloud Storage. Solution: use a Google BigQuery SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, please refer to the following docs:

1. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#sdk-install
2. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/python-guide
3. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil